# AngularJS and Karma - include or require files

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I've been coding using AngularJS with Karma/Jasmine for unit tests for a while (a couple of months, which I think makes me almost an old hand).  I've always kind of wanted a way to make reuseable functions in my Karma testing, but had resigned myself to there being no good way to do it.

I've recently also started using protractor, which provides end to end testing.  In protractor there is a require syntax to include one file into another, allowing us to create library functions.  This is incredibly convenient, and I'd like something similar in Karma/Jasmine.

I haven't found quite where in protractor this capability exists, but it clearly doesn't exist in Karma.  Has anyone found or implemented a similar capability?

Comment: What do you mean by "reusable functions"?

Comment: As an example, my controllers have a standard pattern, so there are some describe and it blocks that are the same in every test.  I'd like to put those into a library function, and simply call "testStandardFunctions()" rather than duplicating those tests in every controller spec.

Comment: wouldn't these includes go into your karma config file?

Comment: Oh.  I've never seen it done that way, perhaps.  If that works then definitely.  I'll try tonight

Comment: FYI: the reason that protractor tests can use 'require' is because they are all run with node.js - so the require() function is just plain old node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, following jl's suggestion, I end up with this code, which works very well.  Clearly my javascript knowledge was a flaw, I hadn't really considered the fact this all lives in a global address space.

First, I create a file "base_controller.spec.js".  In this file I declare a global object:

```
var BaseController = 
  {
    baseBeforeEach: function() {
      // mock Application to allow us to inject our own dependencies
      beforeEach(angular.mock.module('bProject'));

      // create the custom mocks on the root scope
      beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, _$httpBackend_, SidebarService, $state, BreadcrumbService ){
        //create an empty scope
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope.$state = $state;
        scope.breadcrumb = BreadcrumbService;

        // we're just declaring the httpBackend here, we're not setting up expectations or when's - they change on each test
        scope.httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        // setup the project id to a known value
        scope.setupSidebar = SidebarService.sidebar;
        scope.setupSidebar.projectId = 2;

      }));
    },

    baseAfterEach: function() { 
      afterEach(function() {
        scope.$digest();
        scope.httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        scope.httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
      });    
    }
  };
```

Then, I just use BaseController in my tests:

```
describe( 'Risk functionality.', function() {
  BaseController.baseBeforeEach();
  BaseController.baseAfterEach();

  describe( 'Risks list controller.', function() {
```

This example is reasonably trivial, although having the mocking standard on each controller is nice.  But I have a set of standard tests I do on every controller, and this method will let me do it.

Something to watch out for is the order of the includes in your karma configuration - you need to include this file early or else some modules cannot see it.

I'd give jl an upvote, but it was a comment, so I can't!!

Comment: no problem :) i'm sure there are more elegant solutions but this one is simple and easy to understand.

Comment: Agree.  Far easier than I had imagined.  Makes me wonder whether I really needed to use astrolabe with protractor....it was cool how it let me do requires, turns out I didn't really need them!